# I'm calling another page on click button in Django Framework but it is not working

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have attached the necessary code and javascript function as well as the Django code.
I'm trying to navigate to the result.htm from index.html  on click button on "RUN" but the below code is not working to navigate to result.htm.

> index.html

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input class="bg-yellow text-white" id="RUN" href={% url 'result' %}  value="RUN" name="runModel" type="submit" onclick="sendValuesToBack()">
        </form>
   </li>
   
        <input type="image" onclick="openSettingForm()" alt="submit" data-modal-target="#modal" class="img" style="width:80px;height:70px;" src="{% static 'AutoGenerateML/assets/img/Setting.jpg'%}">
</ol>
```

> sendvaluesback() function in javascript

```
function sendValuesToBack()
            {

                let j,
                    i,
                    arry1D = [];

                for(j=0;j!=countName;j++) {
                    var inputs = document.getElementById("formId"+j).elements;

                    var e = document.getElementById("activationFunction"+j);

                    console.log("Activation Function Final:",e.id);

                    var sv = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

                    console.log("me option:",sv);

                    if (!arry1D[j]) arry1D[j] = []
                    arry1D[j][0] = "formId" + j;
                    arry1D[j][1] = sv;

                    console.log("---------------Form--------------------");
                    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                        if (inputs[i].nodeName === "INPUT" && inputs[i].type === "text") {
                            console.log("values of form:", inputs[i].value);
                            arry1D[j][i+2]=inputs[i].value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                console.table(arry1D);
                var tk = $(this).attr("data-token")
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'form_post' %}",
                    type:"POST",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data:
                        {
                            'modelCompileParameters':JSON.stringify(modelCompileParameters),
                            'count':JSON.stringify(count),
                            'arry1D':JSON.stringify(arry1D),
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': tk},
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(resp){
                        alert ("resp: "+resp.arry1D);
                    }
                });
                console.table(arry1D);

            }
```

> result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Result Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

> urls.py

```
 path('result/',views.result,name="result"),
```

> View.py

```
def result(request):
    return  render(request,"result.htm")
```

Comment: how does `sendValuesToBack()` look like?

Comment: certain values that I'm sending to Django backend using Ajax

Comment: there's a bug in your code, right? Most likely in the function attached to the button which does not work. So in order to be able to help you, it would be really helpful to see how the code look like. That's why I am asking about it. Vaguely describing the function wont do the trick.

Comment: please check the updated post I have attached my sendvaluesback() function of javascript. I don't think so there is any problem related to this function. Do i need to write down the code to navigate the page in sendvaluesback() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="submit">` can not have `href` attribute, that's why it's not doing anything. So if you are trying to submit the form and then get redirected to the results page, remove the `sendValuesToBack()` attached to button, just submit the form via a proper request and redirect to the result page in the view which is handling the submitted form. If you need any extra data calculated by javascript, attach it to the form `onsubmit` event.

```
function extraCalculations() {
   //do whatever needed and set it as input values in the form?
}


<form action="{% url 'form_post' %}" method="POST" onsubmit="extraCalculations">
...
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

view handling the submitted form:

```
def form_post_view(request):
    # handle request.POST data and the redirect to result page
    return redirect(reverse('result'))
```